# Nextjs new Url structure redirect

Tags: next.js, next.js13, google-crawlers

I have problem when I change url structure of site. Old structure is like `xxxx.com/product/:id/:name` but I have to change it to `xxxx.com/product/:name/:id`.

I already deploy it and google already crawled it so how can I redirect from old url structure to new or how can I delete every old urls from google.

I used App router in `NextJs 13`.

I try to write redirect in `next.config.js` but I think it not detect which part of it is id or name so it cause many redirect issue.